# Identifying terms of a linear recurrence sequence using a congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences

Let $(n_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of integers satisfying a linear recurrence with integer coefficients,
$$ n_{i+\ell} = \sum_{k=0}^{\ell-1} a_k n_{i+k},$$
and for simplicity assume that $a_0 = \pm 1$.
For a modulus $M$, the sequence $(n_i \bmod{M})_{i=0}^\infty$ is periodic with some period $P$. Moreover, choosing $M$ appropriately, we can get $P$ to be as multiplicatively large as we wish. More precisely: Given any integer $P_0 \geq 1$ there exists a modulus $M$ such that the corresponding period $P$ is a multiple of $P_0$. (This can be inferred e.g. from [M. Ward - The Arithmetical Theory of Linear Recurring Series (1933)](https://doi.org/10.2307/1989851).)

I am interested in a result that's in a similar spirit, but only takes into accound individual entries of $n_i$. Namely, given an integer $Q$ I would like to recognise the residue $i \bmod Q$ based only on $n_i \bmod M$ for some $M$ (which will of course depend on $Q$).

Let me be more specific. For a modulus $M$ and residue $r$ modulo $M$, we can consider the set
$$ I_r  = \{ i \geq 0 \ : \ n_i \equiv r \bmod{M} \}.$$
Let us restrict our attention to values of $r$ that appear as $n_i \bmod M$ for at least one $i$, that is, such that $I_r \neq \emptyset$.
Clearly, this set is periodic with period (at most) $P$. If we were so lucky that there is only one value of $0 \leq i < P$ such that $n_i \equiv r \bmod M$, then the set $I_r$ would simply be a residue class modulo $P$. In general, $I_r$ is a finite union of residue classes modulo $P$, and it is contained in a single residue class modulo
$$ Q := \gcd(I_r - I_r) = \gcd(\{i-j \ : \ n_i \equiv n_j \equiv r \bmod{M}).$$
Note that $Q$ is a divisor of $P$, and of course $Q$ depends on $M$ and $r$. My question is: given an integer $Q_0$, does there always exist $M$ and $r$ such that $Q$ is a multiple of $Q_0$?

As an example, the answer is positive if $(n_i)_{i=0}^\infty = (F_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ is the sequence of Fibonacci numbers. It is well-known that for $i \geq 3$ we have $F_i \mid F_j$ if and only if $i \mid j$. Consequently, we can take $M = F_{Q_0}$ and $r = 0$. This example also shows that we need to be careful with the choice of $r$: Since $F_1=F_2=1$, picking $r = 1$ always leads to $Q = 1$.